# Spring batch application requires redeployment after DB restart

Tags: java, spring-batch

I have a spring batch application (which works as master slave with rabbit MQ messenger) that works perfectly fine until the DB is restarted.

After DB restart, I am getting an error,

```
com.sun.jersey.spi.container.ContainerResponse mapMappableContainerException SEVERE: The exception contained within MappableContainerException could not be mapped to a response, re-throwing to the HTTP container java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/springframework/core/JdkVersion
```

Please help on this.

Answer (score 0):

```
As I know , you need to upgrade your dependency version to solve this problem.
I will update the jar name and version tomorrow cause I am home now.
please try this version or more latest    
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
    <version>1.5.3.RELEASE</version>
    <type>pom</type>
</dependency>
```

Comment: Sure. Thanks for your response. Please update me soon

Comment: I am not using spring boot. in my application it is using spring batch with spring.